# Database design: embedding account attribute in every table or using joining table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

In my database, the account table maintains all accounts registered to my site.
there are also a set of resources which are maintained in resource table called Resource1, Resource2 ... ResourceN, all resources are belonged to some account.

now the problem is should I embed id of account as a column in each table? or using a joining table for each resource? I personally like joining table but not sure which is a better design for this kind of problem.

thank you

Comment: Perhaps it's just me but I'm not sure I understand your tables relationships.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a "joining table" would be more flexible in terms of relationships, e.g. you can have a 1-to-1, 1-to-Many or Many-to-Many relationships between your resource and account records,  although enforcing these relationships can become complicated. If you are not sure what kind of constraints these relations have or will have, I would go with the "joining table" idea.

Comment: thanks. "If you are not sure what kind of constraints these relations have or will have, I would go with the "joining table" idea" inspired me much

Answer (score 1):

How about this design from what I understand from your question.

We create three tables, Accounts, AccountResources, Resources. Using an Association Table would simplify the queries as well.

Table: Accounts
Columns : 
AccountID

Table: AccountResources 
Columns : 
AccountID 
ResourceID

here AccountID and ResourceID form the composite key.

Table : Resources
Columns :
ResourceID